# Wifi will not work. 18.04.2 LTS. New to Linux

Tags: wireless

I am on 18.04.2 LTS. It keeps popping up a window that says "authentication required by wireless network". The correct password has already been input. It just keeps popping up repeatedly.

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. I installed this on an old computer with a new hard drive. Wifi worked before the switch.

I cannot mess with the wifi as it is not mine, but I can connect via ethernet if I need to make adjustments or downloads.

If you care to help, please use baby steps as though I have no clue what I am doing, because I dont.

Output of the command: `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280`

```
Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01) 
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H126.00 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [105b:e017]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: We need a little more info about the wifi card.  Please go to a terminal and type this command **lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280**  and report back what it says.

Comment: That command reported back with my network controller information. Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01) Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H126.00 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [105b:e017] Kernel driver in use: ath9k

Comment: I am typing everything from my phone as my windows desktop is currently not ethernet and the router is across the room. Lol

Comment: Can you please post the output of two commands: 1)  `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` and 2) `nmcli device`. @Nicholaus Hale, please edit your question and then post the output.

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect from an other device ? 
If so you can check the parameters the other device used, in order to set those parameters in the wifi settings :

Settings -> wifi -> click the gear next to your wifi -> security

You do not have to modify anything in the Detail, Identity, IPv4, and IPv6 tabs.
Only in the security tab, check that the right type of security is used to attempt the connexion (WPA, WEP, LEAP and their variant. Also double check your password (and ID if needed).

Comment: The mac address is different via my windows laptop. I tried changing it but it reverted. I also put it into the clone address as well as attempting to manually input all of the addresses. Nothing changed and it reverted after pressing apply.

Comment: It is normal, the MAC address is specific to the device, you cannot set it as easily as an IP. Speaking of IP, you mentioned you tried entering all the address, I think you should let them be set automatically.

Comment: They were all input automatically already. That is why I tried different things. It is back to automatic and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same symptoms in the past on my Ubuntu 16.04 platform.   I am not certain but I seem to remember it was caused by Network Manager being confused because the Wifi interface was also congfigured in /etc/network/interfaces. If that is the case you can probably remove the entry for the wifi card in /etc/network/interfaces and let Nework Manager handle it.  You probably have to delet it in Network manager and start over after reboot.
This is somewhat speculative, since it is a long time since I had that problem.

Comment: I pressed ctrl+alt+t and entered  the command you showed. It says "permission denied".